# why property get added as variable rather than its actual value in the object?

Tags: javascript

Assume

```js
const words = ["hello", "this", "is", "hello", "this", "anything"]

let wordcount = {};
words.forEach((w) => {
  if (wordcount[w]) {
    wordcount.w = wordcount.w++;
  } else {
    wordcount.w = 1;
  }
})
console.log(wordcount)
```

my expected output should be

```
{hello:2,this:2,is:1,anything:1}
```

Instead I am getting this-

```
{w:1}
```

why w get added as property instead of its value.

Comment: This is really unclear. Please add more info. What are you trying to achieve? What is the issue that you're facing? Show the output that you're getting...

Comment: `this` is a reserve keyword in javascript maybe you need a different approach on this

Comment: Please show wordcount being defined.

Comment: Just use `[w]` everywhere instead of `.w`

Comment: @dovidweisz: It is in the post `let wordcount = {};`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let y="test";

//While you use data.y then it means you create or update  attribute with key y
var data={};
data.y=5;
console.log(data);

//While you use data[y] it means you create or update  attribute with key as value of y
data[y]=2;
console.log(data);
```

so you use `wordcount[w]` rather than `wordcount.w`

```js
words=["hello","this","is","hello","this","anything"]
let wordcount={};
words.forEach((w)=>{  
    if(wordcount[w])
    {
      wordcount[w]++;
    }
    else{
         wordcount[w]=1;
    }
})
console.log(wordcount)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```js
let words = ["hello", "this", "is", "hello", "this", "anything"];
let wordCount = {};

words.forEach(w => {
  if (wordCount[w] == undefined) wordCount[w] = 1;
  else wordCount[w]++;
})
console.log(wordCount)
```

Comment: Can as good go all the way: `wordCount[w] = ~~wordCount[w] + 1`.

Comment: `if (wordCount[w] == undefined)` has the same effect as `if (!wordCount[w])`